# Run a script for a SQL query [select from where] on php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to run some SQL queries that I gotten them from a wp database in arrays forms.

For example I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE p.ID in ('800', '808', '569') 
  AND p.post_type = 'post' 
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

How do I execute it in PHP?

So far I have created a new mysqli connection and connected it to the wordpress database I have. How do I run from there?

I was thinking to use the `mysqli::query` function but how to put it in action? I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. I hope it works.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE p.ID in ('800','808', '569') 
AND p.post_type = 'post' 
AND p.post_status = 'publish' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a separate MySQL connection within WordPress, 
WordPress already did it you can simply call the `$wpdb` global object and you can use them

For example

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts p LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id WHERE p.ID in ('800','808', '569') AND p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' ");
```

More info

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

> for me, with the help of @Faisal Shahzad it worked like this

```
 <?php

 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db_db");
 mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
 // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

     // three specific posts
    $q1 = "SELECT post_title, post_content, guid
          FROM wp_posts p
          #LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
          LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
          WHERE p.ID in ('800','808', '569')
          AND p.post_type = 'post'
          AND p.post_status = 'publish'";
   if ($result = $conn->query($q1))
   {
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
       // SHOW three specific posts
    #printf("Title: %s\r\n",$row['_thumbnail_id']); echo "<br><hr>";
    printf("Title: %s\r\n",$row['post_title']); echo "<br><hr>";
    printf("Content: %s\r\n",$row['post_content']); echo "<br><hr>";
    printf("Link: %s\r\n",$row['guid']); echo "<br><hr>";


  }}
 ?>
```